# Passing button id on click in javascript (meteorJs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have this following bootstrap element :

```
<template name = "myAwesomeTemplate">    
<input class="buy btn span4" id= "cat" value ="something" /> 
<input class="buy btn span4" id="dog" value = "something else" /> 
</template>
```

I am trying to pass on the "id" attribute (cat or dog in this example - depending on which button I click) to an method function:

```
Template.myAwesomeTemplate.events({nt 
    'click .buy' : function  (event, template) {
      Meteor.call('buy', this, $(this).attr(id));
    }
});
```

I have tried `this.id`  and `template.find('.buy')` - Nothing exactly words. Anyone has any idea how to do it?

```
Meteor.methods({
     buy: function(thisref,idref) {
        console.log(idref);
});
```

on clicking the first input element, the console should output  "cat", and on clicking the second input element, it should outout "dog".

Also, what exactly does `this` return in this case? It seems to be returning the entire data that this particular template has access to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer....
This worked:

```
Template.myAwesomeTemplate.events({
    'click .buy' : function  (event, template) {
      Meteor.call('buy', this, event.target.id);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$(event.currentTarget)` to get current clicked element jquery reference, in this `.buy`

```
Template.myAwesomeTemplate.events({
    'click .buy' : function  (event, template) {
      Meteor.call('buy', this, $(event.currentTarget).attr("id"));
    }
});
```

and `$(this)` in event handler returns the template data

Comment: I tried this ...unfortunately it did not work and I got the following error:  Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined

Comment: @EnderWiggins ohh, need to give quotes around id and your solution is also fine, that one is much shorter

Comment: ah yes!! it works now. I missed the quotes too. Oops! Thanks for the quick reply though

Comment: Just a clarification: `this` in an event handler does not necessarily refer to the template data. It refers to the data context used to render the element on which the event takes place. However, in this example, those two are the same.

Comment: Thanks!  could you clarify it a little more. That is give an example  when they are not the same?